# How to add private key to keychain in Android?

Tags: security, ssh

I do not want to type my passwords all the time, but instead, just the password to my private keys. 
I am using Samsung Galaxy 4 and Android 5.0.1. 
How can you add private key to your Android keychain?

Comment: Are you talking about *Settings › Security › Certificates* – where you can import such (but then are forced to use a PIN/password on your lockscreen) – or an alternative approach with root powers where you're not forced to that specific lock screen? Or something else altogether, and I just have the wrong associations?

Comment: @Izzy Can you use here ssh keychain? I would love to learn access my phone by my PC such that SSH to my phone and configure the phone in terminal directly in good working environment.

Comment: Sure there are [SSH Clients & Server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients) for Android. But configuring your device from a command prompt would require you knowing the corresponding commands (such as `getprop` and `setprop`, plus a bunch of intents to call etc.pp.), so that's absolutely non-trivial. And a question like "how do I configure my device from the command prompt" would be way too broad here.

Comment: @Izzy Is there any plans about it? It would be great to have terminal configuration option.

Comment: No idea (especially no idea what "plans" you refer to). I'm not aware of a "central CLI for configuration" being even *thought* of. The development team rather focuses on GUI.